# How can I run a non-blocking bash command and block on its output?

Tags: bash, blocking

I'm trying to write a script that will run a program, wait for a certain output from the program, then continue execution (and leave the program running.)
My current code doesn't seem to ever output anything, sed never returns true. 
This echos "Peerflix started" but that's it.

```
exec 3< <(peerflix $1 -p 8888)
echo "Peerflix started."
sed '/server$/q' <&3
echo 'Matched'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [pipes](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Pipes-and-FIFOs.html)!

Use [`mkfifo`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mkfifo) to created a pipe and stream the program's output to it in a non-blocking command. Then use your blocking `sed` to read from that pipe.

Something like(did not test - I don't have `peerflix`):

```
mkfifo myfifo
peerflix $1 -p 8888 > myfifo &
echo "Peerflix started."
sed '/server$/q' myfifo
echo 'Matched'
rm myfifo
```

Comment: This will block at `peerflix $1 -p 8888 > myfifo` unless you explicitly run it in the background. The OP's `exec 3< <(peerflix $1 -p 8888)` process substitution is however, non-blocking

Comment: weirdly enough, it's not working at all. I've realized that I need to be checking stderr instead of stdout, but my solution of https://gist.github.com/anonymous/81d10eb2cc228a7c90fd isn't working at all. (external link cause comments don't have newlines)